# Auto resizing a text area filled with mysql data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm working a small project, and I can't figure out how to setup an auto resize for a textarea field. I'm using PHP.

I made this system to display text templates to copy and paste. The code I found and used is:

```
jQuery.fn.resizeTextarea = function(min) {
  min = min || 75; 
  return this.bind("keyup change click focus", function() {
    var sh = this.scrollHeight;
    $(this).height(function(i, h) {
       return h <= sh && sh != 0 ? sh : min;
    });    
  }).trigger("keyup");
};

$(function() {
  $('#temp').resizeTextarea();
});
</script>
```

[[image: Screenshot of the system]]

And it only resizes the first one in my "`for ($i=1; $i<=$looping; $i++)    {`"

Is there a problem here or something wrong with the code?

REQUEST: I also need something to click on textarea and copy to clipboard, is there any easy fast solution ? :)

Comment: `$('#temp').resizeTextarea();` ID's have to be unique, in your case, only one will be affected, the one with `ID=temp`

Comment: you need to use `class` here instead of id

Comment: Thank you guys, that is something I did not knew ! Any suggestions for click - copy to clipboard ?

Comment: check the [MDN / document.execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) -> Commands / copy -> Copies the current selection to the clipboard

Comment: I've cleaned up some grammatical and layout issues here.